# home page is reloading twice when using intented in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to use intended in **laravel** for redirecting back to the intended location after **login**, but when I try to access the **home page**(ie: the **login page**), the **page** is loading twice.

```
  protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    if($this->guard()->user()->role == 'ADMIN') {

        return Redirect::intended();

    }
```

Comment: Add your intended location code.